# Do JDK classes have any further specifications beyond their Javadoc?

Tags: java, java-8, language-lawyer, javadoc

Do JDK classes have any further specifications beyond their Javadoc? If so, where?

For example, consider `Collections.unmodifiableMap`. [Its Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap-java.util.Map-) doesn't say anything about thread-safety; so just going from the Javadoc, I can't assume that it's safe to expose the resulting map to other threads without taking some special steps of my own to gain thread-safety. But IMHO, any realistic implementation would store the internal map in a `final` field, so in Java 5 and higher, the resulting map will be thread-safe as long as the internal map is (with a "happens-before" relationship between any accesses of the resulting map and any previous modifications to the internal map). That's what the OpenJDK implementation does, for example.

So, how can I figure out if I can portably assume a given behavior?

Comment: As far as I am aware, there are no public specifications for JDK classes other than their Javadocs, except for a handful of classes that have special significance to the VM or language, such as `java.lang.String` and `java.lang.Class`.

Comment: With respect specifically to the thread safety of the object provided by `Collections.unmodifiableMap()`, two memory actions by different threads can conflict only if at least one of them is a write.  `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` necessarily performs writes, so it must be synchronized with respect to other threads that read the object.  But unmodifiability of the provided object is sufficient for thread safety beyond that (because there will be no writes to it), supposing that the underlying map is not directly shared between threads.

Comment: The `final` field safe publication guaranty is more like a safety net in case of an improper publication. You should always avoid relying on it, even for classes where using `final` fields has been specified. It’s very unlikely that you will ever encounter a reason to write code relying on it rather than code doing a correct publication. In case of `unmodifiableMap`, you have to make sure somehow that there really is no write after the publication, i.e. there is a *happens-before* between those writes and the subsequent reads. Having that, the `final` field becomes irrelevant.

Comment: There is JCK (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_Compatibility_Kit) which kind of extra specification layer, but I don't know if anything specific exists for Collections class in particular (and if it is possible to test things like thread safety in this case at all)

Comment: For thread-safety: unless it is specifically stated in the documentation that a class is thread-safe (and in which context), there is no guarantee that it is. It is hard(er) to ensure and guarantee the forever-forward implementation is thread-safe so, when such a design decision is explicitly made, it is usually documented. Classes can be good citizens without boasting extra traits.

Comment: For JDK classes, you can review the source code if you have doubts about the implementation.

Comment: Just checked - only basic behaviour is being checked for unmodifiableMap (it is in JCK-runtime-6a\tests\api\java_util\Collections\CollectionsTests.java test0026() if you want to check it). Nothing about thread safety.

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski No.  JCK is a test suite that tests conformance *with* the specification.  If the tests implemented in JCK do not line up with the written specification, that's a test bug, not an additional spec.

Comment: @bradimus: That sounds like an answer rather than a comment. (But please flesh it out with details like: Where is this "the source code" that I can review? Is there one authoritative implementation that all other implementations are expected to match exactly? What forward-looking guarantees exist?)

Comment: @VinceEmigh: Sadly, no. Simply removing the keyword `final` in the OpenJDK's implementation of `Collections.UnmodifiableMap` (the private nested class used by `Collections.unmodifiableMap`), while not affecting the read-only-ness of the map, would almost completely destroy any thread-safety, since there'd no longer be a happens-before relationship between the internal map being set and the return from `Collections.unmodifiableMap`.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Worse, `unmodifiableList` doesn't even mean the list is actually unmodifiable.  It means it is only unmodifiable _through this reference_.  To render it truly unmodifiable, there's a side condition -- that the underlying list actually not be modified subsequent to wrapping with a UL (or published where someone else might modify it.)

Comment: What do you mean, "one would expect a call like this would break off any mutable references"?  There's no possible way of implementing that in the Java language.  The docs specify that it reads through to the underlying collection; it follows that a change to the underlying collection will be reflected.

Comment: @VinceEmigh And how, exactly, would a library implementation do that, other than eagerly copying the contents (for which we wouldn't need an `unmodifiableList` method)?  The underlying collection is not owned by the library, it is (presumably) owned by the caller of `unmodifiableList` (and is an arbitrary `List`.)  The owner could then freely modify it, as would be their right.

Comment: @VinceEmigh: Re: "Removing the `final` would result in it no longer being read-only": Not at all. It's a private field; if no methods write to it (aside from the constructor, of course), then it's read-only -- but without the thread-safety guarantee.

Comment: @bradimus Reading the source code for a particular version of a particular JDK implementation is useful to help understand how something is implemented, but the specification is the only thing that can tell you what you can count on across implementations (both across vendors, and across versions.)

Comment: @Holger: I'm amazed that you believe that, and even more amazed that two others apparently agree with it. You really have it exactly backwards: immutability is the best approach by default, and only when that's unsuitable should you turn to more elaborate thread-safety mechanisms.

Comment: @ruakh: the map returned by `unmodifiableMap` *is* immutable. You asked specifically for the `final` field guaranty, which is only relevant if you plan improper publication. Using immutable data structures is indeed a very good approach, relying on safety nets for improper publication is not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Javadoc is the specification.  That said, writing good specification is excruciatingly difficult, balancing both not leaving out useful stuff with not overcommitting (and undermining future ability to evolve implementation.)

If I had to guess, I'd say the reason this was left out of the specification (other than possibly oversight) is that any thread-safety would be conditional than the underlying collection (a) not be published and (b) not be modified after the unmodifiable view is created, and this would have to be carefully specified as well.

Comment: OK, thanks. I don't necessarily want to dive *too* deeply into the `Collections.unmodifiableMap` example, since it's just an example of what was motivating this question, but just to be clear: would you assume that the result of `Collections.unmodifiableMap` *is* meant to be thread-safe provided the underlying collection is thread-safe for reads (and not modified after the `Collections.unmodifiableMap` call), and that the reason for the non-specification is just that it's too complicated to specify the details clearly?

Comment: @ruakh In JDK 8, 3 more Javadoc tags were added: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068562. Maybe such an assumption could be inside a `@implnote` tag but such notes cannot be added to every single method in < Java 8 APIs.

Comment: A slightly more pedantically accurate statement is that the Javadoc is the "starting point" for the specification. Some APIs depend on external specifications, and when this is the case, it will be called out in the Javadoc spec.

Also note that some aspects of the specification for a class may appear in the specification for the enclosing package (or module). This is often the case when package-wide (or module-wide) assertions are made, such as the use or otherwise of null argument values.

Answer (score 1):

In the end there's just a continuum from *will never change* over *could change behavior in the next point release* to *just happens to work on your platform*. Even specified behavior can be deprecated and then removed at some point, it just happens extremely rarely (e.g. `Thread.destroy`). So whether you can rely on reasonable-but-unspecified behavior depends how strong a guarantee you need, how much effort you want to spend on coding around things defensively / adding tests to ensure you detect future changes etc.

But yes, the javadocs are the strongest guarantee you can get, everything else means moving onto thinner ice.

Many projects rely on APIs that are not only undocumented but considered internal and ostensibly implementation-specific. `sun.misc.Unsafe` being the prime example here, to the point where most of its features became reified as proper JDK APIs in 9.

In the case of `Collections.unmodifiableMap` if you wanted to be really defensive about safe publication you could insert a store fence after creating it.